# Reuse existing module in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-modules

I am using different variables for different modules but the only difference in them is the name, is there any way to have one module and I can iterate over it using different variables. I don't have to make separate module for it just one module and I can reuse it

```
variable "Nodejs" {
    default = "node"
}
variable "Python" {
    default = "python"
}
variable "Java" {
    default = "java"
}
```

```
module "Nodejs" {
  source        = "./modules/NodeJs"
  name          = var.Nodejs
}

module "Python" {
  source        = "./modules/python"
  name          = var.Python
}

module "Java" {
  source          = "./modules/java"
  name            = var.Java
}
```

Comment: Terraform 0.13 supports for_each for modules. Which version do you use?

Comment: I am using 0.13. How would I loop over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some refactoring for your code, so that you can use [for_each](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/announcing-hashicorp-terraform-0-13) in modules.

An example:

```
variable "languages" {
  default = ["Nodejs", "Python", "Java"]
}

module "language" {
  source   = "./modules/language"  
  for_each = toset(var.languages)  
  
  name     = each.key
}
```

Then you can refer to the individual modules using, e.g.:

```
 module.language["Python"]
```

For this to work you would have to refactor your `modules` folder.